# Laravel Bootstraper align two elements side by side in control group

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to achieve this layout using Laravel [Bootstraper](http://bootstrapper.aws.af.cm/):

---

[image]

---

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
   echo Form::control_group(
      Form::span6_text('something', 'Test 1'),
      Form::span6_text('something', 'Test 2'),
      Form::span6_text('something', 'Test 3')
   );
?>
```

**The problem:**
Bootstraper wraps every form element in seperate `div.control-group`and also, the third element is not showing up:

---

[image]

```
<div class="control-group &lt;input class=" span6"="" type="text" name="something" value="Test 3" id="something">"&gt;<input class="control-label span6" type="text" name="something" value="Test 1" id="something">
<div class="controls">
<input class="span6" type="text" name="something" value="Test 2" id="something">
</div>
</div>
```

---

Can something like this be done with Bootstraper and how? :D

 Thanks!

Comment: can you post the output HTML page?

Comment: @MohamedAbusaid: I just edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Mooseman: yes but this is the closest i got to the end result..

Comment: sorry i totally forgot what the question was, there

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2885/)

```
<div class="small">Control group</div><div class="container well span6"><div class="control-group" >
    <input class="control-label" type="text" name="something" placeholder="Input text element" id="something">
    <input class="control-label" type="text" name="something" placeholder="Input text element" id="something">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="span3" type="button" name="something" value="HTML5 button" id="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
</div>
```